# How to show icon for a window only in the task bar of the screen where it resides?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, taskbar

On Win8 there's an option to show the icons on the task bar but only those corresponding to the windows that actually reside on its screen. This is an awesome feature and now, that I'm on Win7, I'd like to have it here as well.

As far I've googled, that's not a default setting of Win7, so I wonder if there's another solution to that. I haven't found any utilities from third-parties but maybe my google-fu sucks. It's kind of a tricky thing to formulate as a straight question...

I'm talking about this menu in Windows 8.
[image]

Comment: Close-suggesting user - care to elaborate? I'd like to improve the question if possible.

Comment: I'm not the user that voted to close; that said, your question might be clearer if you included a screenshot of the behavior from Windows 8.

Comment: @ncdownpat I added an image that shows the menu from Win 8. Let's hope that it clarifies the question. Thanks for the hint.